# Why can I not redirect STDOUT using "from sys import stdout"?

Tags: python, stdout, python-import, sys

I'm trying to redirect the STDOUT of a python script to a file.

If STDOUT is imported **from** sys, the script's output does **not** get redirected to a file:

```
from sys import stdout
stdout = open("text", "w")
print("Hello")
```

However, if I import **only** sys and use sys.stdout, the script's output is successfully redirected:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open("text", "w")
print("Hello")
```

Why is this? According to [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/187471) the only difference between "import X" and "from X import Y" is the name that is bound. How does this manage to affect stdout?

Comment: I think the first, you are redefining the module as a whole. The second, you are reassigning the reference within the `sys` module

Comment: @cricket_007 No, he's not redefining the module as a whole.

Comment: @abarnert I meant the local variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the only difference is that the name `Y` is bound to `X.Y`.

Either way, binding `Y` to something else isn't going to affect anything in `X`.

---

If it makes it easier, consider this parallel:

```
>>> y = 2
>>> x = y
>>> x = 3
```

Do you expect this to change `y` to `3`? Of course not. But that's exactly the same thing you're doing.

---

If it's still not clear, let's break down what those `import`s actually do.

When you `import sys`, it's equivalent to:

```
sys.modules['sys'] = __import__('sys')
sys = sys.modules['sys']
sys.stdout = open(text, "w")
```

But with the `from sys import stdout`:

```
sys.modules['sys'] = __import__('sys')
stdout = sys.modules['sys'].stdout
stdout = open(text, "w")
```

Comment: Ah, so is the value of sys.stdout essentially copied to a local variable of the same name?

Comment: @Cat Exactly. Well, global, not local, but close enough. And also, it's a bit confusing to talk about "copying" like that. There's a value—a file object somewhere in memory, and there's a variable, `stdout`, in the `sys` module's globals that refers to that value. The value never gets copied, but in a sense the reference to that value does get copied into the name `stdout` in your module's global namespace. People use terminology like `Y is bound to X` to avoid confusion—but of course it just makes things more confusing until you learn that jargon…

Comment: @Cat If you're coming from a language like C, where variables have a memory location, type, and identity, while values are just patterns of bits within a variable. Python isn't like that. Python _values_ have a memory location, type, and identity, and its variables are just names for values stored in a namespace like a module or a class instance. (And a namespace is basically just a dict that you don't have to see directly if you don't want to.)

Comment: I see, I think I get it now. Thanks for the helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as:

```
x = some_object.some_attr
x = open(...)
```

You're not changing `some_object.some_attr` in that case. You're just assigning to a local value.

When you use `sys.stdout = ...` you're actually updating the stdout.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is to create a contextmanager.

```
@contextmanager
def suppress_stdout():
    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        old_stderr = sys.stderr
        sys.stdout = devnull
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout
            sys.stderr = old_stderr
```

and then when I want to suppress the stdout on a certain command:

```
with suppress_stdout():
    # suppressed commands
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself some effort and earn yourself some "Pythonic" points with this little trick:

```
import sys
print('hello', file=sys.stdout)
```

Of course, `print` already goes to `sys.stdout` by default, so maybe I'm missing something.  I'm not sure what's going on with the `open('text', 'w')`, but it might not be necessary if you do it this way :)

In answer to your question about the variable assignment impact, when you use the `=` operator on a variable, you are actually assigning it to the value in the scope dictionary (in this case `globals`).

So when you import `sys`, `sys` gets imported in the `globals` dictionary.

So `globals` looks like,

```
{...,
'sys': <module 'sys' (built-in)>}
```

You can think of the module itself as a dictionary.  So when you do `sys.stdout=` ... that's like doing `globals()['sys'].__dict__['stdout'] =...`

When you just import `stdout`, `globals` looks like:

```
{...,
'stdout': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>}
```

Thus when you do `stdout=...` you're really directly replacing that key in the dictionary:

`globals()['stdout'] = ...`

Hopefully that helps add a little clarity!

Comment: This isn't quite right—it's `globals()['sys'].__dict__['STDOUT']`. Of course the relevant effects would be the same if modules were just dicts rather than objects that have dicts, so the explanation still works, but it would be an even better illustration if it exactly matched what you could see by playing around in the interactive interpreter, rather than raising an `AttributeError`..

Comment: Also, I know the OP used `STDOUT` in the text of his question, but it would be better to correct that and use the actual name `stdout` than to demonstrate with the non-existent name `STDOUT`.

Comment: agreed :) I'll make the relevant changes.  You know, in case some stumbles on here and just picks a random answer.